# Class not found in job with protected variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a Job, but when i set the line:

```
protected $param;
```

to pass the data from __construct to handle() I start getting this error:

```
Class not found
```

When I removed the  protected $param; line, the Job works perfectly. But I'm not able to get the data. What can I do to fix this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Repositories\ProductRepository;

class ImportProducts extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $param;


    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($param)
    {
        $this->param = $param;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //$products = $this->param['products'];
        exit();

    }
}
```

This is the entire error message:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class does not exist    
in Container.php line 734
    at ReflectionClass->__construct('') in Container.php line 734
    at Container->build('', array()) in Container.php line 629
    at Container->make('', array()) in Application.php line 697
    at Application->make('') in Job.php line 154
    at Job->resolve('') in Job.php line 210
    at Job->failed() in SyncQueue.php line 153
    at SyncQueue->handleFailedJob(object(SyncJob)) in SyncQueue.php line 36
    at SyncQueue->push(object(ImportProducts), '', 'upload_products_file') in Queue.php line 40
    at Queue->pushOn('upload_products_file', object(ImportProducts)) in Dispatcher.php line 135
    at Dispatcher->pushCommandToQueue(object(SyncQueue), object(ImportProducts)) in Dispatcher.php line 117
    at Dispatcher->dispatchToQueue(object(ImportProducts)) in Dispatcher.php line 66
    at Dispatcher->dispatch(object(ImportProducts)) in DispatchesJobs.php line 17
    at Controller->dispatch(object(ImportProducts)) in ProductController.php line 656
    at ProductController->importProducts(object(Request))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(ProductController), 'importProducts'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 80
    at Controller->callAction('importProducts', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
    at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(ProductController), object(Route), 'importProducts') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
    at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
    at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(ProductController), object(Route), object(Request), 'importProducts') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController', 'importProducts') in Route.php line 174
    at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: When you're getting this error **Class not found** which class is it trying to find?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I'm not sure which class it is trying to find. I tried to understand the message, but I couldn't. I edited the question with the entire error message. Can you check please?

Comment: Is that the whole stacktrace, because it looks like few lines are missing at the beginning? :)

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I added some lines at the beginning. Sorry for that. ;D

Comment: I think you need a parent::__construct(); in your constructor

Comment: @WouterVanDamme I believe this is not necessary since the `Job` class that's being extended is an abstract class with no constructor.

Comment: @WouterVanDamme If I add parent::__construct(); to the constructor I receive this: Cannot call constructor

Answer (score 0):

When a job use `SerializesModels` trait expect a Eloquent model in the constructor.

You gave something different from an Eloquent Model in the constructor and Laravel, because the trait SerializesModels is trying to reconstruct the Eloquent object from the class of `$param`, but it cannot find it.

Try to remove `SerializesModels` from the traits of the job.